# cakephp 2 threaded not showing children

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hi i don't know what is wrong with the threaded of cakephp 2 please help

when i use threaded without condition it will show its children

```
$category = $this->Category->find('threaded');
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [name] => Affinity Collection
                    [parent_id] => 0                   
                    [lft] => 25
                    [rght] => 30
                    [alias] => affinity-collection
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Category] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 113
                                    [name] => Core samples
                                    [parent_id] => 11

                                  )
                            )
                    )
```

but when i use this with condition it won't show its parent

```
 $this->Category->find('threaded',array('conditions'=>array('Category.id'=>11)));
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [name] => Affinity Collection
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [lft] => 25
                    [rght] => 30
                    [alias] => affinity-collection
                    [status] => 0
                )



            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

please help why it is not showing the children when use with condition

Comment: Could you post the models' relations and the query generated by cakephp?, it seems that it could be because the inner child is also a Category, so when you search with Category.id=11 it doesn't match the child

Comment: there is no relation in category Model only var $actsAs = array('Tree'); and query generated is SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`parent_id`,  `Category`.`lft`, `Category`.`rght` FROM `categories` AS `Category` WHERE `Category`.`id` = 11 ORDER BY `Category`.`name` ASC

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you are asking for all categories with an id of 11. Insted you should ask for all categories that are children of categorie 11.

You could use your left and right columns to get a nested array (keyword Tree behaviour). Try this:

```
$parentCategorie = $this->Categorie->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Categorie.id' => 11
    )
);

$children = $this->Categorie->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Categorie.lft BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($parentCategorie['Categorie']['lft'], $parentCategorie['Categorie'])['rght']
    )
);
```

Comment: yes i solved it by $children = $this->Categorie->find('threaded', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Categorie.lft BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($parentCategorie['Categorie']['lft'], $parentCategorie['Categorie'])['rght']
    )
);

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best chance you have to achive what you want is to use the children method of the Tree behavior.
You coul use it as follows

```
$parent=$this->Category->find('first',
    array('conditions'=>array('Category.id'=>11)));
$this->Category->children($parent['Category']['id']);
```